# Winforms combobox canot bind the new value member.parameter name:value

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding

this a cod when a do it at for combobox its came me an thes messag 
i donot whers a wrong "canot bind the new value member.parameter name:value"

```
        Dim sql3 As String
           Dim dt4 As New DataTable

            sql3 = "SELECT     class.class_name, teacher.first_name, course.cours_name, class.class_char" _
    & " FROM         class INNER JOIN" _
    & "                      lecture ON class.class_num = lecture.class_num INNER JOIN" _
    & "                      course ON lecture.cours_num = course.cours_num INNER JOIN" _
    & "                      teacher ON lecture.teacher_id = teacher.teacher_id" _
    & " WHERE     (class.class_name = '" & cbox_class.Text & "') AND(teacher.first_name = '" & cbox_teacher_name.Text & "')"
            Dim da5 As New SqlDataAdapter()
            da5 = New SqlDataAdapter(sql3, conn)
            da5.Fill(dt4)
            cbox_cours.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        cbox_cours.DataSource = dt4
            cbox_cours.DisplayMember = "cours_name"
            cbox_cours.ValueMember = "cours_num"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not returning cours_num

change

```
"SELECT     class.class_name, teacher.first_name, course.cours_name, class.class_char" _
```

to

```
"SELECT     class.class_name, teacher.first_name, course.cours_name, course.cours_num, class.class_char" _
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no `cours_num` field returned by your query. You must either include the missing field in your query or correct the `ValueMember` value so that the correct field is used.

As a side note, you should be aware that your current code is wide open for [Sql injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should be using parametrized queries rather than concatenate values from UI controls.